# Getting NullPointerException when trying to get data from SQLiteDatabase into Spinner[Android]

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, logcat, sqlite

Helllo people I've got `NullPointerException` in LogCat. When I opened my application, I get force close. Plus, in the LogCat says that Caused by `NullPointerException` at `main.page` `getAllNames()`. So I thought it's something to do with my `getAllNames()` method in my database file.

My codes are below:
TestSpinnerDB.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_test);

        Spinner testSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
        Cursor testCursor = friendDB.getAllNames();
        startManagingCursor(testCursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter testAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, testCursor, from, to);
        testAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        testSpinner.setAdapter(testAdapter);

        testSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                {
                    Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    testSpinnerId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    }
```

BuddyDBAdapter.java

```
public class BuddyDBAdapter extends AnniversaryDBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "name_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "buddiesList";

    public BuddyDBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx);
    }

    public long insertNames(String name)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        return db.insert(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteName(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllNames()
    {
        return db.query(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getName(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor c = db.query(true, CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

This is my LogCat

```
08-30 15:03:53.361: I/dalvikvm(715): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:03:53.381: I/dalvikvm(715): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:03:53.781: D/gralloc_goldfish(715): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-30 15:03:53.871: I/dalvikvm(715): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:03:53.881: I/dalvikvm(715): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:04:06.101: D/AndroidRuntime(715): Shutting down VM
08-30 15:04:06.101: W/dalvikvm(715): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.page/main.page.TestSpinnerDB}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at main.page.BuddyDBAdapter.getAllNames(BuddyDBAdapter.java:35)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at main.page.TestSpinnerDB.onCreate(TestSpinnerDB.java:32)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-30 15:04:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  ... 11 more
08-30 15:04:06.481: I/dalvikvm(715): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:04:06.501: I/dalvikvm(715): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:04:06.661: I/dalvikvm(715): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:04:06.681: I/dalvikvm(715): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:04:10.601: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:04:10.621: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:04:11.011: D/gralloc_goldfish(739): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-30 15:04:11.111: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:04:11.131: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:05:10.671: D/AndroidRuntime(739): Shutting down VM
08-30 15:05:10.671: W/dalvikvm(739): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.page/main.page.TestSpinnerDB}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at main.page.BuddyDBAdapter.getAllNames(BuddyDBAdapter.java:35)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at main.page.TestSpinnerDB.onCreate(TestSpinnerDB.java:32)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-30 15:05:10.711: E/AndroidRuntime(739):  ... 11 more
08-30 15:05:10.881: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:05:10.891: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:05:11.301: I/dalvikvm(739): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:05:11.311: I/dalvikvm(739): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:10:10.791: I/Process(739): Sending signal. PID: 739 SIG: 9
08-30 15:34:24.541: I/dalvikvm(1844): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:34:24.581: I/dalvikvm(1844): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:34:24.861: D/gralloc_goldfish(1844): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-30 15:34:28.141: D/AndroidRuntime(1844): Shutting down VM
08-30 15:34:28.141: W/dalvikvm(1844): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.page/main.page.TestSpinnerDB}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at main.page.BuddyDBAdapter.getAllNames(BuddyDBAdapter.java:35)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at main.page.TestSpinnerDB.onCreate(TestSpinnerDB.java:32)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-30 15:34:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1844):     ... 11 more
08-30 15:34:28.491: I/dalvikvm(1844): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:34:28.511: I/dalvikvm(1844): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:34:28.722: I/dalvikvm(1844): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-30 15:34:28.731: I/dalvikvm(1844): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-30 15:34:30.381: I/Process(1844): Sending signal. PID: 1844 SIG: 9
```

Oh by the way, I've managed to display data into `spinner` like weeks ago, but recently after I've created tables within one database file, I couldn't display data into `spinner`.

I've followed this example [Android: populate a Spinner from a SQLite database](http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-populate-a-spinner-from-your-sqlite-database/) which made me able to display data.

I've followed that example again and I've received `NullPointerException` and force close.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've posted the full code of BuddyDBAdapter.java

Comment: where is the declration of friendDB ?

Comment: @aprian the `CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST` is a `private static String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "buddiesList";` in my BuddyDBAdapter.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one possible thing is,

your `db` object is **null** in `getAllNames()`
 method of **BuddyDBAdapter Class**...

**TRY:**

```
public Cursor getAllNames()
{
  if(db != null)
  return db.query(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);
  return null;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also call

```
BuddyDBAdapter friendDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);
```

in `onCreate()` of **TestSpinnerDB** Activity..

Comment: db object is null? do you mean i need to declare db object like this - `SQLiteDatabase db;` ?

Comment: Post complete code of **BuddyDBAdapter.java** .Also debug `getAllNames()` .

Comment: hey i did what you said and I can open my activity. But there's no data displayed in the spinner. after i open and close `friendDB` i can't open the activity. i'm not sure what and where i did wrong in my codes.

Comment: i've just delcared the friendDB in onCreate() method

Comment: Where is `db.query` the **db** object you declared?

Comment: do you mean declare it in BuddyDBAdapter java?

Answer (score 0):

Where you'd declared `friendDB` in your `onCreate` This is the reason for that `NullpointerException` coming. Try to declare the required `BuddyDBAdapter.class.` Ex,

```
Spinner testSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
BuddyDBAdapter friendDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(); // Declare something like this
Cursor testCursor = friendDB.getAllNames();
startManagingCursor(testCursor);
```

I think you just created `friendDB` as global variable. And, not declared anywhere. Post the full code.

Comment: I declared `friendDB` above onCreate() method - `BuddyDBAdapter friendDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);`. I couldn't declare it in `onCreate()` method because i get the `friendDB.getAllNames()` error.

Comment: oh! i delcared the friendDB in onCreate() method again and there's no error, I'll try again. sorry about that.

Comment: You're not declare the `db` in your adapter.